# Kubernetes can't deploy simple image from Docker hub via Github

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes

I am really new on this kind of stuff, new on Kubernetes and Docker, but already have some experience on Java.

I tried using Docker Hub by connecting it to GitHub.

On my Git-hub there are only 2 codes:

1. Dockerfile
2. Simple hello world Java code.

Every time I run it on Kubernetes and check it with kubectl get pods, I always get CrashLoopBackOff.

I don't understand what's the problem, I already check the code and try to run it on Docker and it works, it prints out hello world. But not on Kubernetes.

This is the code on Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8
COPY helloworld.java .
RUN javac helloworld.java
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "helloworld"]
```

This is the code on simple helloworld java

```
public class helloworld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

What I expected is: as I run this on Kubernetes I hope it says that it's ready and I can deploy it to an IP and show simple hello world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't specify how you executed it, I will assume you've been using `kubectl run` (by default creates a deployment) or a manifest defining a deployment. If so, then the `CrashLoopBackOff` is expected because [deployments](http://kubernetesbyexample.com/deployments/) are for long-running processes. You Java code is not long-running. It prints something and then exits, that is, doesn't have an endless loop in there.

So either do the `System.out.println` in a loop (with a sleep inbetween?) or use a run command or a workload type (such as [jobs](http://kubernetesbyexample.com/jobs/)) that is for one-off execution.

BTW, even with deployments, you should still be able to use [kubectl logs](http://kubernetesbyexample.com/logging/) to see the output from the first execution.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming some things too. Assuming that the image runs fine, and that the only issue is that a docker container gets shut down when there are no processes running, what you have to do is to force a process to be running for while.

So, you can do:

`kubectl run hello-world --image YOUR-IMAGE sleep 100`

This will create a `deployment` hello-world. A pod `hello-world-xxxxxx-xxxx` will run for 100 seconds, then it will die, and a new container will be create for another 100 seconds, and so on.

When you get the confirmation, you do:

`kubectl get po`

Copy the name of the pod, and get the logs:

`kubectl logs YOUR-POD-NAME`

And you should see the hello world.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the location for copy, run and entrypoint commands.
Prefix the filename with the path, say

COPY helloworld.java /helloworld.java
RUN javac /helloworld.java
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "/helloworld]